# Two Nginx server block only one works with React app

Tags: linux, nginx

I want to host several react app on my linux(CentOS) server with nginx.

currently I have two server block in nginx.conf.

First server is where I proxy different request to different server.
Second server is my react app.

I couldn't get my react app host by nginx.

**Block 1**

```
server {
    listen 80
    server_name localhost
    root /usr/share/nginx/html

    ...
    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3010
    }
    ...
}
```

**Block 2**

```
server {
        listen          3010;
        listen          [::]:3010;
        server_name     localhost;
        root            /home/administrator/Projects/app1/build;
        index           index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
```

When I using telnet to check the server is hosting or not. only port 80 is listening.
No server is listening on port 3010.

How should I change my Nginx configuration to make it works?

**Update**

I check the nginx error log and I got

> 1862#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:3010 failed (13: Permission denied)

I've search on it and there are a lot answer about non-root user cannot listen to port below 1024

But the server is trying to bind on 3010

Do I still have to add run nginx by root?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to SELinux security policy. If You check on the below command and see `http` is only allowed to bind on the list of ports.

```
[root@localhost]# semanage port -l | grep http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

Maybe you can use any of the listed ports or add your custom port using the below command

```
$ semanage port -a -t http_port_t  -p tcp 3010
```

If `semanage` command is not installed, you can check using `yum provides semanage` command to identify which package to install.